# Dynamically populating image source with multiple instances of a JavaScript function

Tags: javascript

The popup in my fiddle works great except if i want to make more than one, i have to create multiple divs with multiple images and multiple IDs, which works fine but is time consuming and messy.

Edit: Each popup will have a different image

My goal is to:

1) Still create multiple IDs/images for each popup, but make a function where the script figures out the IDs dynamically so i'm not making a separate function for each ID.

OR

2) Create the whole popup HTML markup in javascript which will allow me to dynamically populate the image source in the popup with a data-attribute. When the link is clicked, it will create the popup and the image src in the popup can be dynamically populated with a data-src from that link.

Are any of these methods in the right direction? I need to use pure JS.

http://jsfiddle.net/6sh0dogr/5/

Basic JS function from fiddle:

```
var popup = document.getElementById('light');
var background = document.getElementById('fade');

function popit() {

    popup.style.display = 'block';
    popup.style.top = parseInt(pageYOffset, 10) + 150;
    background.style.display = 'block';

}

function closeit() {

    popup.style.display = 'none';
    background.style.display = 'none';

}
```

Comment: Why not use a `class` instead of an `ID` ? This way it doesn't have to be unique.

Comment: If you're not using jQuery you're forced to use `getElementsByClassName()` which gets an array of ALL classes that matches the name.
@OP you can pass a parameter to your `popit()` function with the parameter being the ID of the popup you want to display.

Comment: @Press, no he isn't.. document.querySelectorAll(CSSSelector). where CSSSelector is a string like "div.className"

Comment: If he uses the same class name it will still get all classes with the same name. Since ID are unique, and each popup is its own instance, why not use and pass an ID as a param.

Comment: Each pop is its own instance but the image will be different for each popup.

Comment: the 'image' should be described in css.. update your question if this is an actual project concern

Answer (score 0):

Give your divs id like this:

```
 element.id = "image_div"+Math.round(Math.random()*10000);
```

Now you can select all divs with:

```
 var nodeList = document.querySelectorAll("div[id*='image_div']");

 for (var i = 0; i < nodeList.length; ++i)
 {
     nodeList[i].addEventListener("click", popit.bind(null, nodeList[i].id), false);
 }
```

`div[id*='image_div']` is a selector. `*=` means *contains*. So this selector selects all div elements with `id` that contains `image_div`.

Now we can attach an event handler (click) to all divs using a for loop that iterates over the nodeList. The id of the div is passed on through the bind function to the function popit.

```
function popit(popId) {
   var node = document.getElementById(popId);
   popup.style.display = 'block';
   popup.style.top = parseInt(pageYOffset, 10) + 150;
   background.style.display = 'block';

}
```

Comment: don't bother with the bind.. just use popit as a handler.. mouse click event will pass e.target as the element

Comment: `nodeList[i].addEventListener("click", popit, false)' and 'function  popit(e) { var popup = e.target; ....`

Comment: Using `*=` on the `id` attribute is a really good sign that you should be using classes instead.

Comment: @BrettCaswell `e.target` only works well when there are no child elements inside the element. If not you need additional coding to check if the target was the parent and not its child.

Comment: no.. that has no bearing on the element that is raising the event. you're attaching an event to each element in the nodelist.. the e.target will be the element that raises the event

Comment: @BrettCaswell consider this `<div><img></div>`. When I attach a handler to the parent div. But click the img an event is fired. But the event target will be the `img` element and not the div.http://jsfiddle.net/k3nod6dp/1/

Comment: in that case.. `popit.bind(null, {"target":nodeList[i]});`

Comment: @BrettCaswell. I don't like that. You're passing a reference to an element in the DOM. This could (in older browsers) lead to memory leaks. Passing the id is better. It's just a string.

Comment: appreciate the reply, thank you.  but this is way out of my league, any chance at a fiddle?

Comment: @Mouser: That’s not the situation that leads to memory leaks in older browsers, unless you’re talking about *really* old browsers with murky behaviour. Note that `addEventListener` works on none of them.

Comment: @minitech Doesn't this create a circular reference between domNode - JavaScript?

Comment: @user3869231 No problem. This fiddle is inspired on my solution, but translated to your application: http://jsfiddle.net/5282y8y4/5/

Comment: @Mouser: IE6 doesn’t support `bind`, `addEventListener`, or `querySelectorAll`… circular references aren’t an issue.